# How can I set it so that when a number is pressed it leads to corresponding theorem (or formula)?

Tags: texstudio

Literally, given a Theorem and a number, is there any way to make it move to that theorem when the number is pressed? Can anyone provide example or Templates?

For example, let's see the next image : [image]
[image]

Notice the underlined pinked numbers. How can we make it possible so that

1. If we press the number (23) or (24), then it leads to the formula (23), (24)
2. If we press the Construction 4.9.1., then it leads to the corresponding constructoin 4.9.1

?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Search for "hyperref package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{22}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{One}
\setcounter{section}{8}
\section{One}
\begin{construction}[title name]\label{cons:4.9.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:23}
    E=m\cdot c^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:24}
    c=\sqrt{\frac{E}{m}}
\end{equation}
\end{construction}
\clearpage

Refer to the construction \ref{cons:4.9.1}.

Refer to the equation (\ref{eqn:23}) and (\ref{eqn:24}).
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: O.K. I somewhat understand. It was helpful~ Thank you for helps!~